# JQuery UI Tabs Issue with Knockout binding of observableArray

Tags: jquery, user-interface, knockout.js, tabs

I get an odd issue from JQuery UI Tabs:

When i binding Data with Knockout to some Textfields, the JQuery UI Tabs don't work anymore. If I disable ko.applyBinding, then it works. If i remove then "with" or the "foreach" tag from knockout, the tabs are working fine.

But if I use the "with" tag, an i want a JQuery Tab in this area, then the Tabs stop working without any error in the jsConsole.

Some backgrounds:

- the Data comes as an Array from JSON. They are circular references.
- I use only the First entry of the Array. The newer comes more then One, but i must use the observaleArray to use the Data.
- i want to display the referenced Data in a Tab. The Example down do not have this implanted, because the tabs wont work.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/7rPR3/23/

Codes:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="with: First">
    <!-- <tbody> -->
        <tr>
            <td>PersoNr:</td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: PersoNr" type="text" disabled /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: Name" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vorname:</td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: Vorname" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Save:</td>
            <td><button data-bind="click: $root.saveData">Save</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">

                <div id="StammTabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#StammAdresseTab">Adresse</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#StammFunktionTab">Funktion</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#StammVertragTab">Vertragsdaten</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#StammTeamTab">Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#StammBankSozTab">Bankdaten/Sozialvers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#StammKrankenversicherungTab">Krankenvers.</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#StammSonstigesTab">Sonstiges</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#StammUnterlagenTab">Unterlagen</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="StammAdresseTab">

                    </div>
                    <div id="StammFunktionTab">
                        <p>StammFunktionTab</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="StammVertragTab">
                        <p>StammVertragTab</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="StammTeamTab">
                        <p>StammTeamTab</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="StammBankSozTab">
                        <p>StammBankSozTab</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="StammKrankenversicherungTab">
                        <p>StammKrankenversicherungTab</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="StammSonstigesTab">
                        <p>StammSonstigesTab</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="StammUnterlagenTab">
                        <p>StammUnterlagenTab</p>
                    </div>
                </div>




            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

JS:

```
      var tabs = $("#StammTabs").tabs({
          select: function (event, ui) {
              alert("hallo!");
          }
      });



var data = [];




    var stammViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.stammPersoNr = 'XX0000';
        self.data = ko.observable(data);
        self.dataArray = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        self.First = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.dataArray()[0];
        });

        var json = '[{"$id":"1","ID":299,"PersoNr":"TZ1155","Name":"Mustermann","Vorname":"Martin","Geschlecht":"m","Eintritt":null,"Austritt":"2999-01-01T00:00:00","Geburtsdatum":null,"Staatsangehörigkeit":null,"aktuellerStatus":8,"Intranet":false,"Bild":null,"Bemerkung":null,"User":null,"Userdatum":null,"StammAdr":[{"$id":"2","ID":205,"PersoNr":"TZ1155","Datum":"2008-01-15T00:00:00","StraßeNr":"Irgendwo. 2","PLZ":12345,"Ort":"Berlin","Tel":null,"Mobil":null,"EMail":null,"User":null,"Userdatum":null,"Stamm":{"$ref":"1"}}]}]';

        alert(json);

        self.loadData = function () {
            if (self.stammPersoNr !== '') {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: " /echo/json/",
                            data: {
                                json:json
                            },
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, self.dataArray);
                   }
        });
            } else {

            }

        };
        self.loadData();

    };     

    ko.applyBindings(new stammViewModel());
```

Comment: Could you explain what is not working in the given fiddle ? Or could you post one that reproduces the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for interesting question. The correct answer is hidden in your experiments with `foreach` and `with` bindings, which both cause complete rerendering of child nodes.

Take a look how your fiddle is executed step-by-step:

1. UI Tabs are initialized within #StammTabs element
2. Your model initializes
3. `tbody` content is saved somewhere and detached from DOM since observable `First` is not initialized yet (normal behaviour of `with` binding).
4. Model loads data.
5. Observable `First` is filled up with object.
6. New `tbody` is generated by copying saved `tbody` with given values.
7. New `tbody` is attached to DOM (event handlers are not copied from original `tbody`).
8. Tabs looks styled but event handlers are not reassigned (tabs do not work).

The obvious solution is to intercept moment when content is rendered and somehow reinitialize tabs. `foreach` binding has a build-in option `afterRender` that allows to hook this moment. I guess that `with` binding has not `afterRender` option (I tried it but looks like the option is not working with `with`).

So IMHO the best solution is to use custom binding for UI Tabs widget initializing. This approach guarantees that tabs will be initialized properly after each change of `First` value. For example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uiTabs = {
    init: function(el){
        $(el).tabs({ select: function(){ alert("hello"); } });
    }
};
```

and explicitly bind to #StammTabs:

```
<div id="StammTabs" data-bind="uiTabs: 1">
```

Any value is allowable in this case, but you can rewrite the custom binding to get more flexible behaviour.

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7rPR3/24/